# Searching one-to-one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have three models, let's call them models A, B and C.

A and B share one-to-one relationship, A can exists without B but B must always be linked to A. C has many-to-one relation with B. Or in other words:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
  #properties

class ModelB(models.Model):
  a_link = models.OneToOneField(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='a_link')
  #rest of the properties

class ModelC(models.Model):
  set = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now, my question is, I want to find all A's that user has, by checking what Cs they have been tagged in. Can I just do search `ModelA.objects.filter(a_link__modelc__user=user)` or do I need to first search for Cs in their own query, then select Bs from them and look for their relationship with A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(a_link__modelc__user=user).distinct()
```

The `.distinct()` is useful here to avoid that the same `ModelA` is in the `QuerySet` multiple times if there are multiple related `ModelC`s that have as `user` the *`user`* object.

Since the `related_name` is however the name of the relation in *reverse*, you might want to rename this to for example:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
  #properties

class ModelB(models.Model):
    a_link = models.OneToOneField(
        ModelA,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='b_object'
    )
    # rest of the properties

class ModelC(models.Model):
    set = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

then the query is thus:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(b_object__modelc__user=user).distinct()
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Aaah, so that's why I kept breaking. I figured related_name went "To object being linked", instead "from object being linked". Thanks for the clarifcation!